# QUERY RegEx and &

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I've got a long google sheets `QUERY`, part of which is this:

`=QUERY(LOOKUP!$A$4:$H,"Select count(B) where UPPER(D) matches 'OK' and UPPER(H) matches '.*(?:^|,|,\s)"&REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE($Q3,"\s|-",""),"` `\w+` `")&"(?:,\s|,|$).*' and (UPPER(C) contains '"&REGEXEXTRACT($Q3, "\{(\w+)\}")&"' or UPPER(F) contains '"&REGEXEXTRACT($Q3, "\{(\w+)\}")&"') limit 1 label count(B) ''",0)`

Basically if I have an entry like `apple {pear}`, I only want the apple bit to be matched as part of the query. This works absolutely fine except if I put an `&` in the bit to match eg. `apple&banana {pear}`the match fails even though `apple&pear`is definetely present in the lookup so I think the issue is with my `RegEx`. I've tried just replacing `\w+` selector at the seperated spot in in the `RegEx` with `.*` above but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It would make more sense to replace `\w+` with `\w+(?:&\w+)*`

Comment: Thanks @wiktor. I ended up using `[A-z0-9&]+` which seems to work but if you can see an issue I'll give your suggestion a go. Cheers

Comment: Oh, yeah, there are issues, or at least one. Do not use `[A-z]`. 
See [here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). I posted an answer with explanations.

Comment: See my answer below, if it works for you, please consider accepting/upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to replace `\w+` with `\w+(?:&\w+)*`.

The `\w+(?:&\w+)*` pattern matches

- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars, letters, digits or `_`
- `(?:&\w+)*` - matches 0 or more occurrences of:

  - `&` - a `&` char
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars, letters, digits or `_`

If you do not want to match `_`, use

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:&[A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

Note that `[A-Za-z0-9&]+` can also be used if you do not care if there are consectuvie `&` chars in the input (and want to match it).